# Slightly Translated Parallel Electrical Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

My apologies for the vague title, but I simply do not not how else I could express it. As I was studying for my physics electrical exam, I found nodal analysis quite useful; however, I do not know how to apply nodal analysis to further simplify the following example:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bridge circuit, re-drawn to confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you removed R3 you would get this: -

[image]

With 1 volt applied you get 0.5 volts on the points where R3 was removed. This means that whatever value of R3 was present there would be zero current through it. So, it boils down to analysing it without R3 and clearly it becomes a trivial problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the \$Y-\Delta\$ transformation:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform)

[image: Y-Delta transformation]

You find that

$$\begin{align}
R_1 &= \frac{R_bR_c}{R_a+R_b+R_c} \\
R_2 &= \frac{R_aR_c}{R_a+R_b+R_c} \\
R_3 &= \frac{R_aR_b}{R_a+R_b+R_c}
\end{align}$$

Once you have transformed a triangle (either R1-R2-R3 or R3-R4-R5), you will find that you can simplify the equivalent resistance as usual.

For example, given that they're all \$100\Omega\$, \$R_1' = R_2' = R_3' = \frac{100^2}{300}\Omega = \frac{100}{3}\Omega\$. You can then work out the equivalent resistance

$$R_{eq} = \frac{100}{3}\Omega + \frac{1}{2}\left( 100 + \frac{100}{3}\right)\Omega = 100\Omega$$

In order to do the same with Nodal analysis, you want to calculate the current through the voltage source. The equivalent resistance is then the applied voltage divided by the current through the source. But if you really want to use nodal analysis on *this* circuit, you will have to resort to **source shifting**. By doing so, you can convert the voltage sources to their Northon equivalent, allowing you to use nodal analysis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgqEyX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can apply Nodal analysis in the usual way and calculate the total current by summing the currents through R4 and R5.

Also consider looking up the **Mesh current analysis**, as this method doesn't require you to do source-shifting.

*Another* alternative, is by using **Modified** nodal analysis. You then add *one unknown* (the current through the voltage source \$i_V\$) and *one equation* (the applied voltage equation \$v_+ - v_- = 1V\$). You can then apply regular Nodal analysis, but using \$i_V\$ as an additional term in the other KCL equations. The added equation allows the system of equations to be solved.